# Webflux/Angular slow Server side events vs http-client

Tags: spring, angular, server-sent-events, spring-webflux, angular-httpclient

I am running a demo locally with angular and webflux hitting a webflux endpoint which returns 3 photos with size ~ (20MB, 1k, 20MB) from db

The difference on timing using http-client and SSE on angular service are huge,  am i missing something here?

[image]

spring controller

```
@RestController
public class PhotoController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/photos")
    public Flux<Photo> getAllPhoto() {
        return photoService.findAll();
    }
}
```

Angular service

```
     getWithGET(): Observable<any> {
         return this.http.get(this.URL);
     }

    getWithSSE(): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create(obs => {
            const es = new EventSource(this.URL);
            es.addEventListener('message', (evt) => {
                obs.next(evt);
            });
            return () => es.close()
        });
    }
```

angular component

```
clickGET() {
  this.requestsService.getWithGET()
  .subscribe(
    data => console.log(data);

}
clickSSE() {
  this.requestsService.getWithSSE()
  .pipe(take(3))
  .subscribe(
    message  => console.log(message );
  }
```

Comment: are the subsequent calles also this slow? or it just the first one?

Comment: @piotrszybicki there is one request with first service and one with second , the getWithSSE is much much slower than getWithGET, both requests bring back same data (3 objects with size 20MB, 1k, 20MB)

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning a stream of photos like you think. You need to tell your method to use the correct response type.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/photos", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Photo> getAllPhoto() {
    return photoService.findAll();
}
```

Which will let your Angular app handle the events correctly, and much more quickly.